# WaitForSingleObject returning ERROR_IO_PENDING

Tags: windows, multithreading, events, waitforsingleobject, waitformultipleobjects

Does anyone know why WaitForSingleObject() or WaitForMultipleObjects() would return ERROR_IO_PENDING where the object i'm waiting on is an event created with CreateEvent()?

In my testing i've tried WFSO and WFMO, manual and auto, INFINITE and 5000, and as soon as I call WaitFor* I get immediately back ERROR_IO_PENDING.

What on earth can be pending about an event object? The point of them is that you wait on them. This event is not part of an OVERLAPPED and nothing to do with an IO call. It is just being used as a one-shot flag for my worker thread to exit (which is SetEvent()ed by another thread).

So - question is - ERROR_IO_PENDING coming back from WFSO - and ideas?

Rich

Comment: Just to reiterate: my WFSO is returning immediately with ERROR_IO_PENDING, not honouring INFINITE or any timeout value. Does not care if the event is signalled or not, just returns.

Comment: Used those wait calls lots, never seen that error.

Comment: Do you mean that `WaitForSingleObject` returned `WAIT_FAILED` and `GetLastError` returned ERROR_IO_PENDING?  Please provide a short, complete test program that demonstrates the problem you are having.